# How to change draw order by line property with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

What I want to do it change the Z order of of a line on this chart based on the `label` attribute. For example, here I would like to make "Label2" plot on top. What I tried to do was mutate the data_all array to put the element I want on top first in the list, though I could not get that work. How can I change the plot order?

So I am creating an array of objects that I can put right into the "data part of chart js like so

```
        data_all=[]
    
        var s1 = {
          label: 'Label1',
          borderColor: '#00ffff',
          fill: false,
          data: [ 
          
          {x: '2021-06-25 11:00:00', y:50.5401942},
          
          {x: '2021-06-25 12:00:00', y:49.9631549},
              
          {x: '2021-06-25 13:00:00', y:50.0555899}]

          data_all.push(s1)

        var s2 = {
          label: 'Label2',
          borderColor: '#00ffff',
          fill: false,
          data: [ 
          
          {x: '2021-06-25 11:00:00', y:50.5401942},
          
          {x: '2021-06-25 12:00:00', y:49.9631549},
              
          {x: '2021-06-25 13:00:00', y:50.0555899}]

          data_all.push(s2)
```

Then I create a chart by passing `data_all` in to a chart variable.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('plotAll').getContext('2d');
            

var plotall = new Chart(ctx, {
                  type: 'line',
                  data: { datasets: data_all },
                  options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    zoom: {
                            enabled: true,
                            mode: 'x'
                        },
                    pan: {
                      enabled: true,
                      mode: 'xy'
                        },
                      
    
                    scales: {
                      xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time'
                      }]
                    },
                    
                  }
                });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the `order` property in the dataset, the lower this is, the sooner it will draw that dataset, see example, noramally red line would overlap blue line, now its reversed:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'red',
        order: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'blue',
        order: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```